# Why won't my socket connect over the LAN when the GPRS is connected on Windows Mobile 6?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-mobile, compact-framework, routes

We have a Compact Framework 3.5 application that performs an end of day download job over a network cradle.

The device is a Motorola MC9500 with Windows Mobile 6.1 Professional.

In order to do this we create a `Socket` class and call `Connect()`

But it only works if the GPRS is not connected.

If the GPRS is connected, the method times out.

Our solution is to programatically power off the phone when the device is put in the cradle, and on again when it's removed.

But that's very brute force, we don't understand WHY it doesn't work, when it should!

Here's the code for connecting (`sServerIPAddress == "192.168.27.107"`):

```
oEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(sServerIPAddress), i);
oSock = new Socket(oEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
oSock.Connect(oEndPoint);
```

Here's the routing table when both interfaces are connected:

```
Destination     Netmask         Gateway         Metric
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         192.168.27.1    20
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         10.212.14.71    50
10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0       10.212.14.71    50
10.212.14.71    255.255.255.255 127.0.0.1       50
10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255 10.212.14.71    50
127.0.0.0       255.0.0.0       127.0.0.1       1
* 192.168.27.0  255.255.255.0   192.168.27.52   20 *
192.168.27.52   255.255.255.255 127.0.0.1       20
192.168.27.255  255.255.255.255 192.168.27.52   20
224.0.0.0       240.0.0.0       192.168.27.52   20
224.0.0.0       240.0.0.0       10.212.14.71    50
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 10.212.14.71    1
255.255.255.255 255.255.255.255 192.168.27.52   1
```

As far as I can tell that should pick the LAN for the target address

I don't see how the WinMo Connection Manager should have anything to do with this, surely down at the IP level only the routing table matters for getting a connection going?

Can anybody tell me why it only works when GPRS is off and how to do it properly?

Thanks,

James.

Comment: Since `192.168.27.107` can only be accessible in your LAN. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: Which we have a route to, via the networked cradle. I've added a highlight to the routing table showing that we have a route to `192.168.27.107`

Comment: Have you tried setting the `LocalEndPoint` for the socket? Maybe this will force the correct interface selection. If it works, you can look further why this interface is not being selected automatically, considering, now, that there is no problem related to the GPRS being turned on.

Comment: No, we haven't, but we shall try that. Thanks.

Comment: That was a working solution Vladimir, thank you.
Please add it as an Answer so I can tick the solution provided box.

Answer (score 0):

My best **guess** would be that your device can only connect to one port at a time - either GPRS or LAN.

Before you try connecting to your LAN, can you do a search to see if any other Socket is open?

If so, can you close it?

If the close is successful, can you now establish your LAN connection?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input but there is no unreasonable limit on number of open sockets. We have however found a solution, you have to manually force the local end point to be the IP address of the interface you want to out of with Socket.Bind()